# Joomla Hikashop missing order: how to tell if has been deleted?

Tags: joomla-3.4, hikashop

There was an order placed in Hikashop (mails sent, paybox payment received), but we can no longer find it in the back-end.

Its order_id is missing in the tables hikashop_order, hikashop_order_product and hikashop_history.

Any other table to look at? Any logfile?
My best guess is that the order was erased from back-end. If so, how to prove it?

For the next times, may playing with [onAfterOrderDelete](http://www.hikashop.com/support/documentation/62-hikashop-developer-documentation.html#onAfterOrderDelete) help in any way?

```
function onAfterOrderDelete($elements){
    if(!is_array($elements)){
        $elements = array($elements);
    }
    $database = JFactory::getDBO();

    foreach($elements as $key => $val){
        $elements[$key] = $database->Quote($val);
    }

    $query='DELETE FROM '.hikashop_table('history').' WHERE history_order_id IN ('.implode(',',$elements).')';

    //add some log message here?

    $database->setQuery($query);
    $database->query();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: if it's deleted, then it's deleted. Only a backup of the database at that time may bring it back.

Comment: Sadly, the deletion happened before the backup ; no log at all ; thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Note that with recent versions of HikaShop, you can go in the menu Customers>Emails history in order to look at all the emails that have been sent by HikaShop.
So even if the order was deleted and you don't have a backup, it might be possible to find the notification emails relative to this order with all the information of the order.